# Apache: allow only to files inside a specific directory read another file

Tags: apache

I have several files inside a directory A. Those files have PHP scripts which read the content inside another file inside the directory B.

Now I want just **only those files** inside the directory A be able to read the file inside the directory B. No one else.

Is that possible **without modifying** the files with the PHP scripts inside and their permissions (`rwx`) and `user:group`?

This is my `phpinfo()` output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23310548/

Comment: You will need to give some more details on your php setup. How is it set up? Apache Module? FPM?

Comment: @BenCummins how can I know that? Is it possble in some of them (apache module, FPM, etc)? I don't care about changing my set up.

Comment: @BenCummins I have just edited my question.

Comment: That's not apache?

Comment: @BenCummins sorry, what do you mean? I have installed Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 15.10.